# How to calculate $\Delta$ in conic sections?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, circles, conic-sections

When learning conic section I learnt about $\Delta$.

For any conic in general form : $ax^2 + 2hxy + by^2 + 2gx + 2fy + c = 0$

Here $\Delta=abc +2fgh - af^2 - bg^2 -ch^2$

- The conic is said to be pair of straight line if $\Delta =0$
- a circle if $\Delta \neq 0$ , $a = b$ , $h =0$
- a parabola if $\Delta \neq 0$ , $h^2 = ab$
- an ellipse if $\Delta \neq 0$ , $h^2 < ab$
- an hyberbola if $\Delta \neq 0$ , $h^2 >ab$
- a rectangular hyperbola if it follows the above condition and $a + b = 0$

Here how was $\Delta$ derived from the above conic equation and how is it used to find out which type of conic is this? (In other words I want proof of derivation of **$\Delta$ and its applications too**. )

Also when I read the word $\Delta$ first thing that comes to my mind is determinants. Is $\Delta$ related to the determinant of some sort of above general conic equation?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_of_axes#Elimination_of_the_xy_term_by_the_rotation_formula

Comment: I need more simpler solution. I don't know if that really clears my doubt as I am having a hard time understanding it.

Comment: you  got the solution??